# Variable edge/subdag reuse in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

So, I was changing the DAG of my work ETL when I found something like this.

```py
# (...)

def build_spark_task(**kwargs) -> SparkTaskConfig:
    spark_task = SparkTaskConfig(...)

    # (...)
    
    return spark_task

def get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(**kwargs) -> (SparkKubernetesOperator, SparkKubernetesSensor):
    create_k8s_app = SparkKubernetesOperator(...)  # the task
    wait_app_completion = SparkKubernetesSensor(...)  # the task sensor

    # (...)

    return create_k8s_app, wait_app_completion


# Bronze layer stuff
task_bronze = build_spark_task(...)

# Silver layer stuff
task_silver = build_spark_task(...)

# Some other ETL
task_etl_1 = build_spark_task(...)

# Some other ETL 2
task_etl_2 = build_spark_task(...)

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval=SCHEDULE,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    catchup=False,
    concurrency=10,
    template_searchpath=TEMPLATE_DIR,
) as dag:

    start_dag = DummyOperator(task_id="start_dag")
    end_dag = DummyOperator(task_id="end_dag")

    run_bronze, wait_bronze = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_bronze)

    run_silver, wait_silver = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_silver)

    run_etl_1, wait_etl_1 = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_etl_1)

    run_etl_2, wait_etl_2 = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_etl_2)

    # Main path
    dag_build = start_dag >> run_bronze >> wait_bronze >> run_silver >> wait_silver

    # ETL 1 path
    dag_build >> run_etl_1, wait_etl_1 >> end_dag

    # ETL 2 path
    dag_build >> run_etl_2 >> wait_etl_2 >> end_dag
```

which results in a DAG like the below.

```
start_dag -> run_bronze -> wait_bronze -> run_silver -> (...)

                      -> run_etl_1 -> wait_etl_1 -\
(...) -> wait_silver /                             -> end_dag
                     \-> run_etl_2 -> wait_etl_2 -/
```

I thought that as a "run_" process should be followed by its respective "wait_", so I could replace the return of that function with something like

```py
def get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(**kwargs) -> (SparkKubernetesOperator, SparkKubernetesSensor):
    create_k8s_app = SparkKubernetesOperator(...)  # the task
    wait_app_completion = SparkKubernetesSensor(...)  # the task sensor

    # (...)

    return create_k8s_app >> wait_app_completion  # <== to this
```

and we would then do a cleaner code (IMHO)

```py
    run_bronze = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_bronze)

    run_silver = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_silver)

    run_etl_1 = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_etl_1)

    run_etl_2 = get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(task_etl_2)

    # Main path
    dag_build = start_dag >> run_bronze >> run_silver >> end_dag

    # ETL 1 path
    dag_build >> run_etl_1 >> end_dag

    # ETL 2 path
    dag_build >> run_etl_2 >> end_dag
```

But, these edits didn't result in that DAG I was looking for. Instead, it had some "run_" tasks starting from nowhere, and the "wait_" ones were joining them with the main path edge.

How to use Python variables to reflect more than a DAG's node and enable DRYing code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the cleaner way to do it, but if you want to "fix" your DAG, just pass the `dag` as an argument of the function, assign it to the `dag` parameter of the operator, use the connection definition (`>>`) and don't return anything from the function.

Since you're in the context of the DAG (`with DAG(...) as dag`) Airflow does the assignment behind the scenes, but when you get out of that scope (inside a Python function like `get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple`) you are out of that context.

Your function will look like this:

```py
def get_spark_k8s_tasks_tuple(dag, **kwargs) -> None:
    create_k8s_app = SparkKubernetesOperator(..., dag=dag)  # the task
    wait_app_completion = SparkKubernetesSensor(..., dag=dag)  # the task sensor

    # (...)

    create_k8s_app >> wait_app_completion
    # NO return
```